# Javascript encrypt

Tags: javascript, html, security, encryption

I need a simple javascript function that allows me to encrypt textarea data with a key (The key is the users password stored as a hashed session variable, printed by PHP into a field)

I essentially want the textarea data to be encrypted when the user clicks a button within the form.

EDIT: There obviously appears to be some ambiguity. The person who i don't want intercepting that data is the MITM. Basically, the javascript function serves to encrypt the data before it gets sent. Here's a source mockup

```
function encrypt()
 {
   var key = <?php echo $_SESSION[password]; ?>;
   encrypts(getElementbyID['content'].value, key)
 }
```

Then on the server side

```
function decrypt()
{
   $key = $_SESSION[password];
   decrypts($_POST[data], key);
 }
```

I just need a encrypt + decrypt algorithm
Thanks

Comment: javascript encryption with a key? You may as well hide your doorkey under the mat, but put a sign on the door indicating which mat its under.

Comment: Encryption is hard. You won't find a *simple* function to do it.

Comment: @Jamiec — as opposed to encryption *without* a key?!

Comment: What problem do you think encryption is going to solve?

Comment: If you need data secrecy use ssl....

Comment: @fatfredyy — The assumes the problem is "Stopping the data being sniffed in transit".

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? The client can obviously decrypt everything, and somebody listening in on the traffic can get the key since "The key is [...] printed by PHP into a field". So @fatfredyy is right, you need SSL and not such a broken scheme.

Comment: @Quentin Encryption is easy, key-management is hard.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you are doing it is probably better to use **HTTPS**.

If it's not possible to use HTTPS, you would need a asymetic encryption to make this secure. Have a look at [jscryptolib](http://code.google.com/p/jscryptolib/). It supports public key cryptography like RSA. You would need to send the public key to the client, encrypt the message and decode it with the private key on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to do that?

If you need to protect users' input, **use HTTPS as your transport mechanism.**

Encryption in script on the browser is quite open to manipulation and interception. Maybe if you used a public key algorithm and only transferred the public key in the hidden field you speak of, you could keep prying eyes from reading contents, but even then it's easy for a third party to modify the contents of your HTTP traffic without detection.

Weak security is no security at all.

Comment: It is possible (but not likely) that this question makes sense: If he is already using HTTPS the key is secure. He then might store the encrypted data locally or send it to some other (unsecure) server for storage.

Comment: ... except that he does decrypt on the server, rather than just store.

Comment: I'm currently in Lao.  round-trip to my server in Germany by port: 4080: 1x, 80: 2x, 443: 10x.  ssl is attracting big brothers world wide - everybody seems to be intercepting it.  80 I'm sure is intercepted for commercial use.  high ports are the way to go.

Comment: @ccyoung: You can do SSL over high ports, it doesn't have to be 443.